# How do I use an external library path with C project in Neovim?

Tags: c, neovim, codewarrior

I'm using VS Code to write C, which then gets compiled in an old version of CodeWarrior to be used on a microcontroller.

VS Code has an include path section in the config of the C/C++ extension, where we give it the path for the microcontroller libraries. Is there any simple way to replicate this in NeoVim?

I saw another post about `.clangd` file, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

NeoVim is an editor, not a full Integrated Development Environment like VSCode. However, NeoVim is heavily customisable via plugins. If you are using a relatively new version of NeoVim, you may want to look into the [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) plugin, which makes integration with [language servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) like [clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/) easier (a .clangd file is part of the configuration for this setup).

In particular, if you install both `clang` and the nvim-lspconfig plugin, you can check `:h lspconfig-all` and search for `## Clangd` to get an example neovim configuration. External files like .clangd will also be required for project-wide settings.